# Windows10でProxy Auto Configurationができない

Tags: windows, network, windows-10, proxy

Windows10で特定のIPからの通信のみをプロキシを経由させて行いたいです。
WindowsではProxy Auto Configuration(PAC)というものをつかってプロキシの設定ができるので下記のような設定をしています。
しかし、なぜか思い通りに動きません。

下記の例では125.29.56.129への通信だった場合にのみ192.168.1.16:11161に飛ばすようにしています
しかしうまく行きません。

[Can't read PAC files referenced by file protocol - Browsers | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/administration/cannot-read-pac-file)
このページにローカルにPACを保存して`file://`でアクセスするとうまく読み込まないということが書いてあったのでPACはLAN内のWebサーバに格納しています

さらに考えられることとして、当該IPアドレスにアクセスするアプリケーションがWindows標準ではなく、独自のHTTPライブラリを使っていたりするとこの設定の対象外になるのであろうかと(予想)思っているのですが、そのようなことは起こり得るのでしょうか?

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (host.indexOf("125.29.56.129") >= 0 || url.indexOf("125.29.56.129")) {
        return "HTTPS 192.168.1.16:11161; DIRECT";
    } else {
        return "DIRECT";
    }
}
```

Comment: 具体的にはどのアプリで動作確認を行っていますか？